# Is this parametric curve a rotated parabola?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a parametric curve that is quadratic in both x(a) and y(a).  Specifically,

$$x(a) = -a^2 +150a$$
$$y(a) = -3a^2 + 500a$$
It looks like a rotated parabola.  How can I be sure?

See my Maple worksheet.

Thanks,
Matt
 [image]

Comment: what is $y-3x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for large $a$ the functions are asymptotic to $(x,y)=(-a^2,-3a^2)$; hence the line $y=3x$ must be the axis of symmetry if this is to be a parabola. By comparison, the standard parabola has $x=0$ as axis of symmetry. This suggests the change of coordinates $u=y-3x,\, v=x+3y$, chosen such that $u=0$ is the line $y=3x$ and the $uv$-axes are orthogonal. In these coordinates, we immediately have  $$u=y-3x=50a\implies a=u/50\implies v=1650a-10a^2=31u-\frac{1}{50}u^2$$
which is clearly a parabola.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Solve for $a^2,a$ in terms of $x,y$

Use $a^2=(a)^2$ to eliminate $a$

Finally use [Rotation of axes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_of_axes#Elimination_of_the_xy_term_by_the_rotation_formula) to eliminate $xy$ term